# How can I compound/combine the webdriver locator?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

If I have this structure:

```
<Employees>
    <Employee id="3">Tom</Employee>
    <Employee id="3">Meghna</Employee>
</Employees>
```

How can I use locators with the `wait.until(..)` command to hold till `employee` with `Id="3"` and `text="Tom"` exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with `text()` in xpath to find elements by text

```
//Employee[@id='3'][text()='Tom']
```

Comment: Looks good! Consider using contains() and normalize-space() xpath functions to make it even more stable.

Comment: @automatictester I left it for OP to learn on those contexts as whole bunch of things available on net

Comment: @Oren Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/155831) if it helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`//Employee[@id='3' and normalize-space()='Tom']`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below xpath

```
//Employee[@id='3'][contains(text(),'Tom')]
```

Comment: Thanks, but in a  scenario where  exists a user called Tom with id=4 .   this would come up with the wrong element

Comment: yea.. in that scenario have to mention "id"